# Декоратор, адаптер или что то еще

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Для уменьшения связности кода хочу что бы классы максимально сосредотачивались только на своих задачах и не имели понятия о потребностях кода, который их использует. Но коду который их использует необходимы некие дополнительные возможности. Поэтому необходимо реализовать нечто, что расширяло бы возможности класса. Однако я запутался какой паттерн здесь применим.

Т.е. я хочу иметь некий класс C2. Этот класс может возвращать объекты С1. С1 и С2 являются частью некого пакета, который живет самостоятельной жизнью и не занает, как его используют другие.
Класс С3 использует С2. С2 в С3 возвращает объект класса С1. Но С3 хочет расширенные возможности класса С1, такие какие есть у С4. Поэтому создается новый объект С4, который принимает на вход конструктора объект класса С1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю:

- Паттерн "декоратор" предназначен для расширения возможностей уже существующих функций, а я хочу ввести новые.
- Паттерн "адаптер" предполагает реализацию  методов путем вызова кода из уже существующих классов. Т.е. некое "переименование" методов (трансформация интерфейса), а я хочу оставить уже существующие методы без изменений, и только расширить функционал.

Есть ли какой то паттерн, который подходит  для данной задачи? Или есть  ли какой то способ решить задачу иным образом, сохранив независимость работы С1 и С2, и обеспечив С3 возможностью использовать более расширенный функционал С1?

Comment: мне интересно, кто такие вопросы минусует? если не найдете решения (не получится реализовать)  - пишите, постараюсь помочь.

Comment: В том что вы описали пока что не видно никаких проблем. `C1` и `C2` не знают ничего о `C3` и `C4`. `C3` использует `C1`, `C2`, `C4`. `C4` зависит только от `C1`.  Нет ни одной лишней зависимости. Что в этой схеме вас не устраивает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public interface A {
    
        void DoSome();
        void DoSome2();
    }
    



public class Aimpl implements A {

   public C c;


    public Aimpl(C c) {
        this.c = c;

    }

    public Aimpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public void DoSome() {
        System.out.println("DoSome in A");
    }

    @Override
    public void DoSome2() {
        System.out.println("DoSome2 in A");
    }
}
```

> Цитата

```
    public interface B {
    
    
        boolean newMethod();
    }
```

> Цитата

```
    public interface C extends A,B {

}

public class Cimpl implements C {

    @Override
    public void DoSome() {

    }

    @Override
    public void DoSome2() {

    }

    @Override
    public void newMethod() {
        System.out.println("newMethod");
    }
}
```

> Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {




        Cimpl cimpl = new Cimpl();

       Aimpl aimpl = new Aimpl(cimpl);

       aimpl.c.newMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно два интейфейса, первый будет работать как АДАПТЕР и будет в себе содержать, интерфейс который будет работать как АПДЕЙТЕР и будет нести в себе новую функциональность, и если вам нужна новая функциональность, вам нужно будет делегировать работу вложеному интейсу с определеным АПДЕЙТЕРОМ

Например у вас есть интерфейс А который будет нести в себе какойто функционал,
и содержать в себе интейфейс В, интерфейс В ето и будешь ваш АПДЕЙТЕР в который
будет нести в себе один метод -NewMethot(), который вы будете вызывать

Comment: Спасибо. А можно ссылку на АПДЕЙТЕР. Не могу найти его описание.

Comment: @Dmitrii Апдейтер это абстракция(интерфейс) а не патерн, через который вы будете вызывать новый функионал.

Comment: Т.е. если вернуться к схемке из вопроса, то вместо С4, который наследует С1 и реализует несколько новых методов, реализуем С4, который реализует  интерфейс А с вложенным B. Причем С1 реализует А без вложенного B. Так я понял?

Comment: @Dmitrii Так как ето АДАПТЕР у вас все класы должны содержать в себе сылку на такой же интерфейс как и сам клас, что бы передать ему работу, ето будет первая цепочка, а вторая ето то что АПДЕЙТЕР, который вобще ниче не знает об остальном мире, его цель попасть в конструктор, нашего первого интерфейса что бы добавить что-то новое. Ето будет выглядеть вот так  интейфейс А собержит с себе интерфейс А который содержит АПДЕЙТЕР

Comment: Можете еще уточнить,  а то не совсем понимаю... Про реализацию паттерна АДАПТЕР с использованием интерфейса А вроде понятно, а как реализуется интерфейс B? Это вложенный в А интерфейс? Т.е.    interface A {
    public interface B{
        void NewMethot();
    }
}